# mysql can't return a row result

Tags: php, mysql

I am connected to the database, a page has lots of content so I'll only share the part that doesnt return a value in php, but it returns a value in MySQL

Here is the code;

```
$query = "SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE id = '17'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query_run);
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: Check for errors with `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`.

Comment: I can run the query on phpmyadmin, works just fine

Comment: Obviously something different is happening when you run it from PHP. That's why you need to put error checking there.

Comment: Do you really have a hard-coded `17` in the PHP script, or is it using a variable?

Comment: 17 is just a part of that query, not a variable. A string. Was just trying to get a result for testing. And there is a row with id=17 in table called users

Comment: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

That is the error from mysql_error() function

Comment: Well there you have it. When you called `mysql_connect()` you left the username blank.

Comment: <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "notsitesi";

$dbhandle = @mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

?>

That's the inc file I'm requiring every page, doesn't seem like it

Comment: Something is going wrong there, because the error message doesn't say `'root'@'localhost'`.

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: And don't use `@` when you're debugging, since it prevents seeing errors.

Comment: I used to use 'XAMPP' and this code was working on my other PC, now I started using WAMP, that's the only difference I believe

Comment: I think you need to set `$password`

Comment: I get `'No database selected'` now, and `Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\NotSitesi\incs\register.inc.php on line 20`, 20th line is `$row = mysql_fetch_row($query_run);`

Answer (score 0):

> Changing the code I shared first to this, solved the problem. Thanks to anyone who tried to help.

```
    $query = "SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE id = '17'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query_run);
    echo $row[0];
```

> And made bit changes to the connect.inc.php which I also shared in comment.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "notsitesi";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed");
}

 ?>
```